# TypeError: (void 0) is not a function when closing modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using `AngularJS` and bundling it with `webpack`. To handle my states I'm using `ui-router`. I've changed the structure of my application so a state loads as a modal. When I close the state (modal) it keeps coming up with the error message:

> TypeError: (void 0) is not a function

I've searched online and there are others but none that seem to give a definitive answer to why this is caused. If I change the function to console.log a message, it does and it doesn't cause that error. Somethings causing the issue when I go from the modal state to any other state. I've been following this article https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-stateful-modals-angularjs-angular-ui-router/. I'll provide the code the structure of my states and the function for closing the modal.

```
$stateProvider
.state('portfolio', {
    url: '/portfolio',
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/portfolio/portfolio.tpl.htm',
    controller: 'portfolioCtrl',
})
.state('portfolio.modal', {
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        "modal": {
            templateUrl: "app/templates/patent/modal.html"
        }
    },
    onEnter: ["$state", function($state) {

        $(document).on("click", ".modal-backdrop, .modal-holder", function() {

            $state.go("portfolio");
        });

    }]

})
.state('portfolio.modal.patent', {
    url: '/:patentId',
        views:{
            "": {
                templateUrl: 'app/templates/patent/case-overview.tpl.htm',
                controller: 'caseOverviewCtrl',
                controllerAs: '$ctrl',

            },
            "details@portfolio.modal.patent": {
                templateUrl: 'app/templates/patent/patent-details.tpl.htm',
                controller: 'patentDetailsCtrl',
                controllerAs: '$ctrl'      
            },
      }
 }
```

**Question**

Why is the error `TypeError: (void 0) is not a function` logging when I close the modal (navigate to a different state on close)?

Comment: When you say you change the function to console.log a message, are you still using the jQuery click handler (`$(document).on("click", [...])`)?

Comment: Yeah replacing the `$state.go` with `console.log`

Answer (score 4):

I have been getting the same error plaguing me recently and the answer turned out to be changing my module prop in ts.config from 'system' to 'amd'.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Hope this helps.

Ps. I would have just put this as a comment rather than a full blown answer but i don't have enough reputation!

Comment: Thank you for replying, I'll give it a bash. It's been plaguing me for about a month